# PowerShell, parsing, problem using a specific string with -match/-like and -split

Tags: string, powershell, comparison-operators

I have a variable that is filled with several lines of text and I am trying to parse the data from it.  Now around the middle of the text is a specific string "Reference(s) :" and I need to get everything from above this specific string.  However every way I have tried has failed.

I tried making it a delimiter

```
$Var.split("Reference(s) :")
```

I tried the below 2 options just to try to capture that one line (because if I can do this, then I know I can pull everything before it).

```
$Var.split("`n") | Where-Object {$_ -match "Reference(s) :"}
```

and

```
$Var.split("`n") | Where-Object {$_ -like "*Reference(s) :*"}
```

and I've tried some if statements (Where $_ is a single line of text)

```
If ($_ -like "*Reference(s) :*") {some logic}
```

I cannot just match "Reference" because that word appears elsewhere in the text....and I am needing this to process several instances of this text.

I think the problem has to do with the parenthesis, the space, and the colon (special characters).  I did try preceding each special character with a ` but that did not seem to work.

Anyone have any ideas?  There has to be a way to match special characters, I just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$var` is truly a single string, you can use `-split` at your reference point and then retrieve the first split string (`[0]`). This will retrieve everything from the start of the string until the split point.

```
($Var -split 'Reference\(s\) :')[0]
```

Since `-split` uses regex matching, you must backslash escape regex special characters to match them literally. Here `(` and `)` are special.

In the future, you can just process your match string using `[regex]::Escape('String')`, and it will do all the escaping for you.

---

If you want the line just before the reference point, you can convert your string into an array. Then return the line above the matching line.

```
foreach ($line in ($Var -split '\r?\n')) {
    if ($line -match 'Reference\(s\) :') { 
        $lastLine
    } else { 
        $lastLine = $line
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I know this is very similar to [AdminOfThings good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63178200/4749264). I was already testing it so figured I'd post.

```
$text = 
@"
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
Reference(s) :
Line5
Line7
Line8
Line9
Line10
"@

($text -Split "Reference\(s\) :")[0]
```

This also works, but for various reasons it's recommended to stay with the PowerShell native split operator:

```
$text.Split([String[]]"Reference(s) :", [StringSplitOptions]::None )[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is using the where method.  You can just use -eq instead of -match if that's the whole line.

```
get-content file

before1
before2
before3
Reference(s) :
after1
after2
after3


(get-content file).where({$_ -match [regex]::escape('Reference(s) :')},'Until')

before1
before2
before3
```